# is it possible to deserialize a hex number in a xml file?

Tags: .net, xml, hex, deserialization

We have XML attributes that we'd like to have expressed in hex numbers (tag = "0x2000") for clarity but the .NET XML deserialize is not liking it one bit...

Answer (score 0):

Possible?  Yes, it's possible.  Valid?  Depends on the schema you're validating against.